# Cannot Uninstall visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uninstallation

Im trying to remove visual studio in azure VM, but I cant uninstalling it the control panel.. When i try to uninstall it this screenshot appears.

I also tried `E:/vs_community.exe /uninstall /force` but gets same error..

Anyone knows some fixed for this?

[image]

Comment: I fixed my problem by deleting the Visual Studio 2015 folder in Program Files (x86). After that, Visual Studio uninstalled normally.

Answer (score 0):

Everywhere on the internet I see that this issue is related to the Fonts (System.Windows.Media.FontFamily)

The solution everyone suggests is to go to C:\Windows and copy the folder Fonts, then paste it in the same directory and replace the fonts with the copied ones. Then try again.

EDIT:

I also found a video explaining what I previously mentioned

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2loJTWaDrts

It seems like a popular solution on the internet.

Comment: sorry for late reply, I had tried this and follow the youtube video. but it seems there is a permission issue. It wouldnt allow me to modify the folder. I already tried deleting it in cmd with admin access but still, I wasnt able to delete it.